# Linear algebra: generalize from characteristic $0$ a problem about polynomial coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $K$ be a field, and let $F$ be a subfield of $K$. Assume that $F$ is infinite. Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial in one variable with coefficients in $K$, and suppose that $p(a) \in F$ whenever $a \in F$. Show that the coefficients of $p$ lie in $F$.

I have an argument that works for characteristic $0$ (though I suspect it's true in general). Here is the idea. The polynomial $p$ is determined up to a constant in $K$ by its formal derivative. So if we know that the coefficients of the formal derivative of $p$ lie in $F$, then the coefficients of $p$ must also lie in $F$, with the exception of potentially the constant term. Then we simply just look at $p(0)$, and we are done.

Can anyone help me generalize or show that this argument can not be generalized?

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ be the degree of the polynomial $p(x) = a_n x^n + \dots +a_1x+a_0$.

Since $F$ is infinite, there exist $n+1$ distinct elements $b_0, b_1, \dots, b_n \in F$.
Call $y_k=p(b_k) \in F$ for $k=0,\dots, n$.

Now, you have
$$\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & b_0 & b_0^2 & \dots & b_0^n \\
1 & b_1 & b_1^2 & \dots & b_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \ddots &  \\
1 & b_n & b_n^2 & \dots & b_n^n \\ 
\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} a_0 \\
a_1 \\
\vdots   \\
a_n\\ 
\end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} y_0 \\
y_1 \\
\vdots   \\
y_n\\ 
\end{matrix} \right)$$
and the $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix is invertible, since it is a Vandermonde matrix. Since all the $b_j$ and $y_k$ are in $F$, necessarily $a_0, \dots, a_n \in F$.